# How use files.get in remote helm charts?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, configmap

I use helm charts from my Nexus. I need include some file to configmap. On a local charts it's working when I include file to helm's dir, but it's not working when I use remote charts. How can I fix it?

my configmap.yaml looks like that now:

```
{{ if $.Values.ConfigMap }}
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: {{ template "obj.fullname" . }}
data:
{{- range $.Values.ConfigMap }}
  {{ .fileName }}: |-
{{ $.Files.Get .fileName | indent 4 -}}
{{ end }}
{{ end }}
---
```

I'll need include different files like yaml, json, certifcates and keys, and sometimes some bynaries

Comment: What do you mean by not working? What error are you getting?
In order to use files.get, the files themselves need to be packed along with the chart.

Comment: That mean helm don't running deployment becose configmap didn't see local file. I can't find error, it was long ago. And I can't include file in charts, becose chart use in different projects. I know helm can't using files from outside and I trying find way which help me. Maybe exist another way which didn't use Files.Get.